# Pandas .plot() call freezing GUI

Tags: user-interface, matplotlib, pandas

I'm attempting to create graphs using pandas on Python 2.7 OSX 10.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import Quandl

pd.options.display.mpl_style = 'default'

TOKEN = 'tWquoUMLCebqSBMbTFNg'

print 'Pandas Version', pd.__version__
print 'Numpy version', np.__version__

uk_df = Quandl.get('OECD/HEALTH_STAT_CICDHOCD_TXCMILTX_GBR', authtoken=TOKEN)

print uk_df.head(8)

uk_df.plot()
```

Output: 
Pandas Version 0.12.0
Numpy version 1.8.0

…and then some data. The Python GUI spaceship attempts to open, but bounces forever. What am I missing here?

I have the latest matplotlib installed as well.

Comment: Presumably this is in the interpreter; Are you using IPython or the default python interpreter?

Comment: Hi Tom, Yes, I'm using IDLE, is iPython a dependent IDE to run code like this?

Comment: It's less of an IDE and more of a souped-up interpreter. Check out their website: http://ipython.org  They and the matplotlib team did some work to make sure the interpreter is still responsive while displaying a graphic.

Comment: Ah, thanks Tom. Yes, I have it running in notebook form now. I'm still stuck in some dependency hell, but that's beyond the scope of this question. Much appreciated.